# GARCH model: convergence of the conditional variance to the unconditional variance

Tags: time-series, garch

Suppose a monthly, stationary time series. The series seems to have some ARCH effects and I model its variance as a GARCH process. I obtain the following output of a GARCH(1,1) model:

- alpha ($\alpha$): 0,07
- beta ($\beta$): 0,7
- intercept ($c$): 0,00008

I obtain the unconditional variance of the GARCH(1,1) model by taking the expectation of the GARCH equation:

$$ E(V_t) = E(c + \alpha\epsilon^2_t+\beta V_{t-1})  $$
$$ V = c + \alpha V + \beta V $$
$$ V = c/(1-\alpha - \beta) $$

But now I would like to assess how many months would it take to a regular shock (e.g., one standard deviation?) to dissipate or the conditional variance converge into its unconditional variance. How would someone do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the nature of the autoregressive components in GARCH, the shocks dissipate at an exponential rate and never fully.* So to answer your question,  for a shock to dissipate fully would take an infinitely long time, and the long-run variance would never be reached, only approched however closely.

Therefore, people study half-life instead:
$$
\ell:=\frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(\sum_{i=1}^s \alpha_i+\sum_{\beta_j}^r \beta_j)}
$$
where $\alpha$s and $\beta$s are the GARCH model coefficients. In the case of a GARCH(1,1),
$$
\ell=\frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(\alpha_1+\beta_1)}.
$$
Half-life tells you after how many periods half of the shock has dissipated.

In your case, $\ell=\frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(0.07+0.70)}\approx 2.65$.

*This is in contrast to an ARCH(s) model where shocks completely dissipate after $s$ periods.

Comment: Thank you! Could you share a reference?

Comment: @JohnDoe, I spent a good while looking for it, but I cannot find the original reference anymore. [Here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=garch+persistence+half+life) are some papers that employ half-life, though. (I have also used half-life in one of my empirical papers, but I do not have a reference for it in the paper, so I will not cite my paper here.)